# HTTP Batch Request Google Analytics Not Working

Tags: google-analytics

As per Google Documentation for batch request for Google Analytics, has been used for sending multiple hits as a single request.
I have tried the URL using an resteasy client but it not works
only a single hit has been registerd in google analytics server.

My question is how to form HTTP Batch request for Google analytics Batch Hit?.

```
POST /batch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fhome
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fabout
v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=pageview&dp=%2Fcontact
```

I have tried normal Batch Request for google also, still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little correction, actually batch was working, you can check in the Realtime->Screens->Last 30 mins. There you can find the list of Activities send. :-)